# R Markdown: displaying summation command in PDF output

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm brand new to R, as in my class just began two days ago. In our first assignment we are to show our work and answers, which are written in R Markdown (inside R Studio) and then output in PDF.

On one question we are asked to display the quadratic equation. I know the command, which I figured out is `$$ x=\frac{ -b \pm \sqrt{ b^2 - 4ac} }{2a} $$`.

After I Knit the file to PDF the equation shows up all nice and pretty. However, I cannot figure out how to also get the command to also display to show my work. If I prefix the command with an asterisk, backslash, hashtag, etc., after I knit the file it shows the prefix and then just displays the quadratic equation but not the command.

I'd ask my prof, but he actually suggested we try Stack Overflow with questions in the syllabus (haha!), then referred to himself as a "facilitator more than a teacher". Hmmm. So here I am.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to insert a chunk with your equation:

````
```
$$ x=\frac{ -b \pm \sqrt{ b^2 - 4ac} }{2a} $$.
```
````

Comment: Thanks!!! Among my many attempts I had tried almost exactly what you typed, except with an "{r}" at the end in following general R syntax, but this just led to an error. I've removed that {r} and it worked out fine. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: If @pachamaltese answered your question, you might accept that answer by clicking on the check arrow.